# Meta-analysis using bootstrapped confidence intervals (non-normal data)

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, meta-analysis

I have the results of two studies (my own and a previous study). I want to perform a small meta-analysis to obtain a better estimate of the effect size.

For the two studies I have the means and 95% CIs (mine were obtained via bootstrapping) for each condition.

I'm not sure how to proceed, since I don't know how to calculate the standard error of each study from the 95% CIs, since the data are not normally distributed.

Comment: Presumably you have the data from your study, can you also get the raw data from the other?

Comment: It would require asking the authors for access, and the data may no longer exist - for the purposes of the question, is it possible to proceed with the assumption that it is not possible?